# how we register oauth redirect uri for google console via php code

Tags: oauth, analytics

**Can we register OAuth redirect URI to google console developers via php code?**
By PHP Code how we add more than 1 OAuth redirect URI, I don't need to add it manually from console.developers.google.com

Answer (score 0):

**No, you cant.** You must write it manually in [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

I think it is there because of security reasons. In case of some kind of attack or if wrong person would get your code, he could just change everything in your developers console within code. He never should be able to do it.

More informations in [Using OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Comment: thanks @Karol , Is there any API of google to achieve this , or anything else to do so ?

Comment: I don't think so, Google wants to do it manually in a page. But you can search for it in Google API Library: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library